# Increase speed of itertools combinations / optimize solution for solving word puzzle

Tags: python, performance, python-itertools

I'm trying to create a dutch version of the following word wheel puzzle for my girlfriend.

You can find the example puzzle here: [etsy word wheel puzzle](https://www.etsy.com/nl/listing/724661721/word-wheel-scramble-74a-houten-puzzel)

The puzzle contains 4 wheels which each contain a "unique" anagram of a seven-letter word. By rotating the wheels correctly, 7 four-letter words appear.

In the original puzzle there are even more combinations with 2,3,4 and 5 four-letter words but for now I'm focussing on the 7 four-letter words.

I'm trying to find possible combinations using python itertools and a list of four-letter words and seven-letter words.

I start by ordering each seven letter word alphabetically (trucker -> cekrtu) and adding them to a set (seven_set).

The problem: with 1052 four-letter words I get a total number of combinations of 277,327,128,892,990,760.

Selecting a smaller set (30) of four-letter words did give 1,2 or 3 seven-letter words, but not four, so I need a big set of four-letter words.

As an example, these 7 four-letter words give a result on the first letters and on the third letters: auto,duif,eend,ogen,papa,tram,vita - 1:voetpad 3:patient

I use the following code to look for possible combinations:

```
for a in itertools.combinations(four_letter_words, 7):
    correct = True
    for x in range(0, 4):
        check_string = a[0][x] + a[1][x] + a[2][x] + a[3][x] + a[4][x] + a[5][x] + a[6][x]
        check_sorted = ''.join(sorted(check_string))
        if check_sorted not in seven_set:
            correct = False
            break
    if correct:
        f = open("options.txt", "a")
        f.write(' '.join(a) + "\n")
        f.close()
```

My question(s):

1. Is there a way to speed up this code?
2. Have I overlooked a way to look for combinations which don't require the high number of iterations? Can I limit the number of four-letter words in a smart way without losing possible combinations? (I already removed all words with q,x or y which are very rare in Dutch)

Link to entire code and the word lists: [Github](https://github.com/oehoe/wordwheel)

Thank you very much for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

To limit the number of iterations I removed all 4 and 7 letter words with letters which were used infrequently. In my case the following letters.

```
['j', 'f', 'c', 'h', 'm', 'w', 'z', 'v', 'b', 'u', 'k', 'p', 'i']
```

I ended up with around 140 4 letter words instead of the 1000+ I had before. The script ran almost two days and I ended up with 1700+ possible combinations.